# How to stop throwing blankets off myself while sleeping?

Tags: sleeping

(I'm not sure if lifehacks is the best category for this, but it's the best I could find.) For a long time now, I've thrown my blankets off myself while I'm sleeping. I know I toss and turn in my sleep, and this results in me being cold in the morning. I hate myself doing this and I want to stop. I absolutely hate pajamas so that's not an option for me. I don't know how I can stop this, or if I can stop this at all. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

Lower your thermostat a few degrees during sleeping hours, so you don't get too warm under the blankets.  Then turn it back up for the morning -- or, if it's a modern thermostat, program the settings for sleeping hours (and while you're away for school or work) and save some money on heat.

Comment: Also check if the blanket allows airflow. Otherwise a heat-bubble will build up beneath. This might be a problem with e.g. synth-fibre blankets.

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to turn this into WebMD but I think your question should be treated as more than a life hack. I would consult with a doctor since what you are experiencing sounds like a reaction to something else. To quote Dr. Rosenberg

- "There are many reasons for tossing and turning. These include sleep apnea, chronic pain, periodic limb movement and acid reflux to name a few. Others include the bedroom environment being too warm or having too much light. In addition, excessive alcohol, caffeine and heavy meals before bed can lead to restless sleep."
  Maybe explore the cause rather than "hack" it. 
  Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to work out why you do it.

Do you in fact get too hot, or it that you dont feel secure and thrash around?  You can buy weighted blankets that whilst thin, leave you feeling more secure.

Answer (score 3):

On one side of the bed, insert the edge of the blanket between the mattress and the bed frame.

Comment: Tuck in on both sides but with enough space to allow yourself and for the sheet and blanket to drop down onto the mattrass.

Comment: if he is getting too hot, that wont help

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, until I moved to Europe and discovered the duvet!. A duvet is like a comforter except that it has a cover that you launder. And the cover is typically made of the same type of fabric as sheets are, s it's comfortable against your skin.

Although you can have both a top sheet and a duvet, many people don't. I just use the duvet in place of a top sheet, because if I used both, the duvet might slide off when I turn over. Because there's just one layer, I find it easy to keep it on me while I sleep.

I find that a duvet helps me to stay at a comfortable temperature throughout the night. When the room is warm, I let the duvet just drape loosely over me. When it's cold, I pull the duvet tightly around me. I even do this (pulling it around me or leaving it loose as needed) in my sleep; it's instinctive.

Comment: What did you use instead of a duvet outside Europe?

Comment: @Neeku a top sheet, with a blanket or a comforter on top of that.

Answer (score 2):

I kick one leg out (I sleep on my side), so that foot is a little cold, but then the rest of me is warm.  It somehow ends up feeling balanced to me.

Answer (score 1):

Get cover clamps or at harbor freight they have these little clamps for tents and I think Walmart has also at certain times of year. I clamp two to a blanket about 2 feet away then you can use a small bungee cord to connect both ends while wrapping someplace on bed frame. I use these because I like a lot of blankets on my bed.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all answers above,

- **Tryout**- I would get an extra size blanket or comforter as it will reduce the frequency/probability of blanket/comforter being thrown off.
- **Considerable** - Pitch in the edges of blanket underneath of mattress as stated
  in above answer
- **Avoidable** - *Adjusting the thermostat before and after sleep is not a good idea
  besides it will add a task in your routine. I would not prefer.*

Comment: If you do not want to adjust the thermostat every day you can buy a programmable one. Set it once, it will do the asked program for many years but you can easily change the settings for special days. Or just set the thermostat a bit lower and wear warmer clothes.